# Posting paid plugin code on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, copyright

We bought a plugin for our site. In one of the plugin folders, we saw a PDF regarding copyright.

That document mentions this:

> Any unauthorized copying, renting, leasing, sublicensing, pledging,
>   conveying, creating any derivative works, or disclosing of modification
>   source codes in any way, porting of the Product to other platforms and
>   content management systems is prohibited without prior written
>   approval from XYZ company name
>
> The source code and files are exclusively owned by XYZ Company name
>   and are subject to US Copyright Law and Copyright Laws of the State of
>   Minnesota, as well as international copyright treaty provisions

In this case, may I post some code from the plugin to Stack Overflow to get help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> may I post some code from the plugin to Stack Overflow to get help?

No.

The copyright is clearly still with the XYZ company - you do not have any right to copy any of the code anywhere else, including Stack Overflow.

The license clearly states that if you wish to do so, you need prior approval from XYZ company.

Assuming you did not get that, you cannot post portions of the code anywhere. If you do have permission, you still need to abide by the rules that the company stipulated.

Comment: they are not at all replying for this from last 2 weeks & even they are not helping me .....

Comment: Well, that's your answer right there. You didn't get permission. You are not allowed to post the code. If you do and they catch you, you will not be in a good legal position.

Comment: is that ever happened before, practically do they worry to take legal actions  and spend so much money and time to take legal actions   ?

Comment: Yes. It did....

Comment: @user12345 - it happens. Stack Overflow certainly gets DMCA takedown notices every now and then.

Comment: after hearing your words, i dont post at all, , but from now i dont buy any paid plugins without proper enquiry....  Thanks for your valuable time & suggestions

Answer (score 3):

Did you ask the company XYZ if you can copy it? If not, or they didn't grant you rights in any way, you may not just copy copyright protected code on SO, or any other site.

Note that when you post code, you are actually redistributing it with a different license, so if you are not the author of the code, you should always ask permission to redistribute it under the license SE uses.

Comment: they are not at all replying for this from last 2 weeks.....

Comment: Then the answer is (still) no.

Comment: `if (!haveGrantedAutorization) { canPost = false; }`

Comment: well, even they are not at all helping me also, i am not asking them to do any extra customization , i am asking which code is reason for that feature..... still they are not replying......

Comment: Sorry for that, but that is not our problem. We can't make them reply. The law just prescribes you can't copy it. Period.

Comment: practically do they worry to take legal actions  and spend so much money and time to take legal actions   ?

Comment: You can always give it a try... I will send you a prison post card if it didn't work out well for you.

Comment: after hearing your words, i dont post at all, , but from now i dont buy any paid plugins without proper enquiry....  Thanks for your valuable time & suggestions

Comment: Although prison is not very likely in this case, you just have to abide the law.